# Finding elements that are unique in one column excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two columns in excel that have some shared data and some unique data to each column. What I want is to have two more columns that will have the data that is in Column A but not B and the data that is in Column B but not in A. I have tried using Vlookups but I don't think I can get what I am looking for by doing this.

Comment: I have tried this but it isn't working.`=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(ISNA(MATCH($A$2:$A$729,$B$2:$B$170,0)),$A$2:$A$729,"x"),ROW(1:1)),"")`

Comment: I've missed that this formula would work only with numbers, but not when cells contains text:)

Comment: Ah okay well thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Col A items not in column B, try this **array-entered** formula (entered in some cell, then fill down until it returns blanks)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ColA,SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(ColA,ColB,0)),ROW(ColA),""),ROWS($1:1))-1),"")
```

and for Col B items not in Column A:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ColB,SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(ColB,ColA,0)),ROW(ColB),""),ROWS($1:1))-1),"")
```

The formulas assume that your data starts in row 2 (row 1 would be a label) and the ranges ColA and ColB also start in Row 2

The formulas also assume no blanks in the data.  If there are empty cells, then use these formulas:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ColA,SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(ColA,ColB,0))*(ColA<>""),ROW(ColA)),ROWS($1:1))-1),"")

=IFERROR(INDEX(ColB,SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH(ColB,ColA,0))*(ColB<>""),ROW(ColB)),ROWS($1:1))-1),"")
```

Example Image:

[image: Results]

Comment: It seems to process something, but it ends up filling the boxes with nothing

Comment: Either every element in Col A is duplicated in Col B, or possibly you did not enter it as an array formula.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I've added example in my response of what I think your data might look like, and the results of the formulas I provided to extract the items in Col A that don't exist in Col B; and the items in Col B that don't exist in Col A.

Comment: I am practicing using the example you gave but when I enter the formula for ColA unique it only shows 5 in each box.

Comment: I selected the boxes under ColA unique, entered the formula replacing ColA and ColB with the actual cells, and then hit ctrl +shift+enter. I think the formula might be off

Comment: @user3285439 No, No. You are entering it incorrectly. Do NOT enter the formula in multiple cells first.   First enter (with ctrl+shift+enter) the formula in a SINGLE cell (e.g. E2 if you are using the above example).  Then select that cell and fill down.  Otherwise the row_index parameter doesn't update, and you only return the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with a PivotTable, if you are prepared to rearrange your data somewhat:

[image: SO21686456 example]